# Linux Only 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0161' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, linux, django, apache, python-3.x

I encountered an error, which only happens on linux server with apache2 running wsgi on django. I do development in Windows then I copy it over to Linux server.

I see the problem is in the string: (Bold part is marked by Django)

> **Društvo t**abornikov - Rod Srnjak Logatec

But this error happens only on one page. The same string is also used on settings page but it displays properly. Also same error pops on the admin page.
In the views.py file I have already set the utf-8 encoding.
The error doesn't happen if I start server without apache with:

```
 python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Trace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://***.***.**/vodnik/eposta/?cid=17

Django Version: 1.10.3
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'vodnik',
 'schedule',
 'djangobower']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /var/www/etaborniki/templates/vodnik/eposta.html, error at line 59
   ascii   49 :     <small style="text-align: justify"><strong>Opomba:</strong> Na dno sporočila bodo avtomatsko dodani podatki roda in
   50 :         obrazložitev namena
   51 :         sporočila, ker je naša aplikacija skladna z zakonom <a href="https://www.uradni-list.si/1/content?id=111442">ZEKom-1</a>.
   52 :     </small>
   53 :     <br/>
   54 :     <small style="text-align: justify"><strong>Soglasje:</strong> S pritiskom na gumb pošlji se z navedenim popolnoma
   55 :         strinjam in prevzemam vso
   56 :         odgovornost. V sporočilu ne smem posredovati kakršnihkoli osebnih podatkov, sovražnega govora ali vsiljene
   57 :         pošte. Strinjam se, da bo moj e-naslov razviden prejemniku in družbi KSoft.Si. Sporočila se hranijo do 3 mesece.
   58 :         Kršitev tega soglasja ali zakonov ZEKom-1, ZEPT in ZVOP-1, se lahko sodno preganja. Za katerokoli kršitev družba
   59 :         KSoft.Si in  {{ rod_ime }}  ne odgovarjata.
   60 :     </small>
   61 : </div>
   62 : 
   63 : {% include 'generic/scripts.html' %}
   64 : {% include 'generic/tinymce.html' %}
   65 : </body>
   66 : </html>
   67 : 

Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/var/www/etaborniki/vodnik/views.py" in eposta
  177.             return render_to_response('vodnik/eposta.html', c)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render_to_response
  21.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, using=using)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  1050.         return render_value_in_context(output, context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_value_in_context
  1028.     value = force_text(value)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_text
  80.                 s = six.text_type(bytes(s), encoding, errors)

Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError at /vodnik/eposta/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0161' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error shows that you have python 2.7 active

```
...

Django Version: 1.10.3
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
...
```

So since you seem to run the development server with `python3` I would assume you would want to do the same with the live version.

Comment: I installed mod_wsgi for python3, but it didn't work either (outdated from apt). So I installed mod_wsgi from github with python3 and it works.